# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer - property can't be set

Tags: c#, properties

SML is a property of regelSML. I want to set regelSML to a value given by Reader.getString(i).

```
if(reader.GetName(i) = "SML") regelSML.SML = reader.GetString(i);
```

Comment: `=` != `==` ....

Comment: `reader.GetName(i) == "SML"`, you want to compare, not to assign.

Comment: oooops. wow. That I didnt see this ..

Answer (score 1):

As clarification, like Guy wrote in the comments above, you are not doing a comparison in the condition. 
A single `=` is for assignments. 
You need the comparison-operator `==`.